# CUBLAS library: find max of actual values rather than absolute values

Tags: cuda, cublas

The CUBLAS library of NVIDIA CUDA allows finding the element/index with maximum **absolute** value (cublasIsamax). Is it possible to find the element/index with the maximum **actual** value somehow, using the CUBLAS reduction functions?

[I am using CUBLAS version 3.2.]

**Edit**
 
Constraint: I cannot alter the state of the production server in any way. This means that I cannot use thrust/cudpp, and that I'm stuck with using an older version of CUBLAS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what "reduction functions" you are referring to.

CUBLAS is basically just a "like-for-like" implementation of BLAS for CUDA devices. It only provides the standard Level 1, 2 and 3 BLAS functions, plus exactly three extensions - geam (scaled matrix addition/transposition), dgmm (diagonalised matrix-matrix dot product) and getrfBatched (batched LU factorisation for many small matrices). None of those functions will find the signed maximum value of a supplied vector or matrix.

NVIDIA ship [cudpp](https://code.google.com/p/cudpp/) and [thrust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust#readme), either of which are probably better for this sort operation. Also, CUBLAS 3.2 is two and a half years old.

As a final comment, I would strong recommend using either the CUBLAS 4.x or CUBLAS 5.x releases. The API and performance of the code has improved considerably, especially for newer hardware.

Comment: I was referring to the sort of parallel reduction functions thrust provides. I am constrained to using only the libraries that are installed on the production server, at least for now. Thrust and cudpp are not available. I guess that leaves me with just the option of implementing the parallel reduction myself.

Comment: Edited the question to include this constraint.

Comment: @fhl: Thrust is a template library. It is only header files and has no runtime component at all. If you pull one of the older branches off their repository, the functions you need to do a reduction will build with the CUDA 3.2 toolchain.